# Copying an Blend Storyboard

Tags: storyboard, expression-blend-3

I have an expression blend 3 solution, that has a few images(my buttons). Now i have a storyboard that plays a certain effect/animation/fade-in on my button. Can i copy the storyboard to my other buttons or must i go an do each animation on it's own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store those storyboards as a style and apply it to all yours buttons.

Here you can read about templates:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx

Here you can look at using `VisualStateManager` (and `Storyboard` in in) withing template:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstategroup(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: And how do i save my storyboard as a style?

Comment: I've extended my answer. Please take a look.